# Why Ricci Flow Always Defines a Riemannian Metric As Long as it Exists

Tags: differential-geometry, ricci-flow

From what I understand, the Ricci flow

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} = -2Ric(g)
\end{equation}

always defines a Riemannian metric as long as it exists. I know that the Riemannian condition is an open condition in the space of symmetric two-tensors, but is that all there is to this statement? I know that certain curvature-related quantities must blow up at the first singular time for the Ricci flow, but may this also be understood in terms of when the two-tensor solution for the Ricci flow looses its definiteness?

Comment: See section 5.3 in Topping’s lectures. https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maseq/topping_RF_mar06.pdf

Comment: @Deane  I can't believe I calculate the Topping's book  carefully but didn't know there was an answer to this question in the book.  Maybe, I need time to read it again.